# Paranthesis over quantifier doubt.

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

Convert the following statement to predicate logic.

At least one router is functioning normally if the throughput is between 100kbps and 500 kbps and the proxy server is not in diagnostic mode.

Solution:

Let the domain be all applications and routers. Let Router(x) be “x is a router”, and let ProxyServer(x) be “x is the proxy server.” Let Diagnostic(x) be “x is in a diagnostic state”. Let ThroughputNormal be “the throughput is between 100kbps and 500 kbps”. Let Functioning(y) be “y is functioning normally”.

∀x (ThroughputNormal ∧(ProxyServer(x)∧ ¬Diagnostic(x))**)** → (∃y Router(y)∧Functioning(y))

---

I think the answer should be

∀x (ThroughputNormal ∧(ProxyServer(x)∧ ¬Diagnostic(x)) → (∃y Router(y)∧Functioning(y))**)**

I am having doubt regarding that paranthesis in bold.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Why my question is being downvoted ? Is it just because I didn't use mathjax ?

Comment: @Shaun The two sentences are *not* equivalences.  The first is $\color{silver}{\big(}\forall x~P(x)\color{silver}{\big)} ~\to~ Q$ the second is $\forall x~\big(P(x) \to Q\big)$

Answer (score 1):

Recall $\forall x~(P(x)\to Q) \iff (\exists x~P(x))\to Q\\ (\forall x~P(x))\to Q\iff \exists x~(P(x)\to Q)$

> > At least one router is functioning normally if the throughput is between 100kbps and 500 kbps and the proxy server is not in diagnostic mode.
>
> ∀x (ThroughputNormal ∧(ProxyServer(x)∧ ¬Diagnostic(x))**)** → (∃y Router(y)∧Functioning(y))

This has the form of $\forall x~(T\wedge P(x))\to Q$.   The order of operations means this is implicitly: $(\forall x~(T\wedge P(x)))\to Q$, and is equivalent to $T~\to~\exists x~\big(P(x)\to Q\big)$

"If throughput is normal then there is a proxy server that if it is not in diagnostic mode, then there is a functioning router."  or "There is a proxy server such that, some router will function normally if throughput is normal and that proxy server is not in diagnostic mode."

This is not *quite* what you want to say.

> ∀x (ThroughputNormal ∧(ProxyServer(x)∧ ¬Diagnostic(x)) → (∃y Router(y)∧Functioning(y))**)**

This has the form of $\forall x~\big(T\wedge P(x)~\to~Q\big)$, which is equivalent to $T~\to~\forall x~(P(x)\to Q)$

"Whenever throughput is normal, any proxyserver that is not in diagnostic mode guarantees that there is a functioning router," or "There is a functioning router if throughput is normal and any proxyserver is not in diagnostic mode."

So, this is *closer* to what you want to say.

---

How many Proxy Servers are there?

Comment: So first sentence basically says that "**all** routers should be proxy server and not diagnostic so that a functioning router could exist". Second one says that "for all x, **if that particular x** is proxy server and not diagnostic then a functioning router exists. So second one is correct right as all routers are not needed to be proxy server for correct functioning of router  .Am I Right?

Comment: can you please reply ?